# Use of bitwise operator in condition - Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `bool'

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I wrote the following code that uses a `bitField` variable as a map for characters to check their presence in a given string:

```
public static bool AllElementsUniqueInASCIIString(string str) {
    int bitField = 0;
    
    foreach (int character in str) {
        int idx = character - 'a';
        int mask = 1 << idx;
        if (bitField | mask == 1)
            return false;
        else
            bitField &= mask;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

The problem is, on the expression `if (bitField | mask == 1)`, the following error is thrown at compile time:

> CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

However, when I replace this line with the following snippet, the code compiles just fine:

```
   int present = bitField | mask;
   if (present == 1)
```

Both `bitField` and `mask` are integer, so what is the matter of this compile error? What syntax should I use to check this condition in one line?

Comment: [For reference, the operator precedence table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) (scroll down a bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need brackets to explicitly express your intentions

```
if ((bitField | mask) == 1)
```

The compiler thinks you are wanting to do the following (due to operator precedence)

```
if (bitField | (mask == 1))
      int    |    bool
```

Which is what the error is telling you

> CS0019    Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and
> 'bool'

In short, *equality* operators have precedence over *Boolean logical OR* or *bitwise logical OR* operators

---

**Additional Resources**

[Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence)

> In an expression with multiple operators, the operators with higher
> precedence are evaluated before the operators with lower precedence